# perl hash ref operator is working weirdly

Tags: perl, hash

I m having a single array ref consisting a list of hash refs.

Here is the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $arrayRef = [
    {
        'URL' => 'http://example.com/1.jpg',
        'ORD' => '1',
    },
    {
        'URL' => 'http://example.com/2.jpg',
        'ORD' => '2',
    },
    {
        'URL' => 'http://example.com/3.jpg',
        'ORD' => '3',
    },
];

print $arrayRef->[0]->{URL},"\n";     # http://example.com/1.jpg
print $arrayRef->[0]{URL},"\n";       # http://example.com/1.jpg
```

Since it is an hash ref i am using `->` operator to get a value, but i m getting the same value without using the `->` operator is it fine?

Comment: perl hash ref operator is working <del>weirdly</del><ins>conveniently</ins>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's valid, a kind of syntactic sugar, and it refers to the same item. The [Perl references tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Arrow-Rule) writes about this